# How to get a json schema from another file?

Tags: file, reference, jsonschema

I want to know how to get a json schema from an other file.

Suppose I have two files, placed in the same directory:

**File 1: person.json**

```
{
    "id":"#person",
    "name": {"type":"string"},
    "age": {"type":"number"},
    "address": {
        "type":"object",
        "properties": {
            "number": {"type":"number"},
            "street": {"type":"string"},
            "city": {"type":"string"}
        }
    }
}
```

**File 2: company.json**

```
{
    "id":"#company",
    "name": {"type":"string"},
    "employees": {
        "type":"array",
        "items" {"$ref":"person.json"}
    }
}
```

As you may observe, "employees" is supposed to be an array of "person". The problem is I don't know how to reference the "person" schema, because it is in a different file.

I am aware that this might be a simple question, and that there are maybe already answers about this, but I have already researched a lot and I don't understand how this is done.

**EDIT 1**

I am using [Tiny Validator 4 (tv4)](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) for schema validation. I am also using QUnit to test if the schemas are working like they should.

Below, I show you a test where the address number is boolean when it should be of type number. The schema validates, when it shouldn't.

```
asyncTest("invalid type for adress number", function() {
    expect(1);
    var jsonObject = {
        name: 'Computers Inc',
        employees: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                age: 29,
                address: {
                    number: 9,
                    street: 'Oak Street',
                    city: 'London'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Mike',
                age: 35,
                address: {
                    number: true,
                    street: 'Big Avenue',
                    city: 'London'
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    // Gets the JSON Schema
    $.getJSON('json_schemas/company.json', function(response) {
        var jsonSchema = response;
        console.log(jsonSchema);

        // Verifies the validity of the JSON object
        var valid = tv4.validate(jsonObject, jsonSchema);
        ok(!valid, "Not valid because Mike's number is a boolean.");
        start();
    });
});
```

After looking at it for a while, I think it is the "$.getJSON" who is messing it up. The "console.log(jsonSchema)" shows that the fetched schema doesn't include the person part. The fetched schema is exactly the one from the "company.json" file.

**EDIT 2**

I think it is working like this. :)

```
asyncTest("invalid type for address number", function() {
    expect(1);
    var jsonObject = {
        name: 'Computers Inc',
        employees: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                age: 29,
                address: {
                    number: 9,
                    street: 'Oak Street',
                    city: 'London'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Mike',
                age: 35,
                address: {
                    number: false,
                    street: 'Big Avenue',
                    city: 'London'
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    tv4.asyncValidate(jsonObject, 'json_schemas/company.json', function(valid) {
        ok(!valid, printMessage(valid));
        start();
    });
});
```

Comment: What you have there looks like it should work.  What's problem are you seeing?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @cloudfeet. I added some more details in the EDIT 1. It seems to be a problem with fetching the schema for validation. Would you please look at it? Thanks again. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your schemas look like they should work - so my guess is that you aren't loading the schemas into your validator properly.

With `tv4` (which you are apparently using), you should be able to see if you are missing any schemas using the `"missing"` property of your results.

```
var result = tv4.validateMultiple(data, schema);
console.log(result.missing); // ['/json_schemas/missing-schema']
```

To fix this, you need to load any schemas you need into `tv4` before validation:

```
tv4.addSchema('/json_schemas/missing-schema', ...)
```

There's also an example script that adds a `tv4.asyncValidate(data, schema, callback)` method, which uses jQuery to fetch missing schemas and try again, which might be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you, @cloudfeet. ;) I think tv4.asyncValidate saved the thing. Would you please see my EDIT 2? I think I used it correctly. Thank you very much. ;)